# Is there a way to stop evaluation immediately?

Tags: evaluation

Sometimes I'll have a loop that I accidentally made too big. I'll evaluate, and MM will try to run through the entire loop. The program itself doesn't actually seem frozen... I can go to Evaluation-> Abort/Interrupt evaluation, but they don't do anything. I can even save while it's doing this!

What seems to kind of work is saving, closing the file, and then going to Evaluation->Quit kernel.

But that's a little ridiculous. Is there really no 'hard kill'?

Thank you!

Comment: If the spin is "tight", it can take some time before MM responds to a kill, if at all. Try putting `TimeConstrained` around your test cases or put in some explicit guard until you're sure they are peachy.

Comment: Okay, but I'm curious: what's the logic behind designing it like this? I'd understand if it wanted to give literally all its resources to computing the code, but it's clearly checking for things like mouse clicks, menu openings, saving, etc. So why not just have something that really kills it?

Comment: Sometimes it works to repeatedly abort the evaluation (on my mac with shortcut cmd+.), it has happened to me before that I was able to kill the evaluation only after hitting the abort shortcut 8 times or so. Maybe it's a matter of killing sub processes individually?

Comment: On Windows you can still kill `MathKernel.exe` in the task manager, it always works :D

Comment: @YungHummmma As you noticed, usually you can kill the kernel instantly by Evaluation -> Quit.  But then you lose all kernel state (definitions made so far, etc.)  Interrupting an evaluation *while maintaining a clean kernel state* is not an easy task at all.  If you [extend Mathematica through C](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/LibraryLink.html) you need to explicitly make your C functions [interruptable](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/ref/callbacks/AbortQ.html), i.e. periodically check for an abort and exit from the function in a clean way, ...

Comment: ... making sure to free all allocated memory and other resources to prevent leaks, and do all this without noticeably decreasing the performance of your function.  Once you try to do this yourself, it'll become very clear why it is not feasible to make any kind of calculation instantaneously interruptible.